# Generic mathematical equation for deriving two numbers from the same pool with a dependency

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Sorry for the title, I did not know how else to describe my question.  I'm a programmer and I'm looking for a general form to answer the following type of question:

It takes 1 hour to produce a widget.  It takes 5 hours and 1 widget to produce a gadget.  If I have 100 hours, how many gadgets can I produce assuming I have no pre-made widgets?

This one seems simple, since it takes 6 hours per gadget, I can make 100 / 6 gadgets in 100 hours.

If I have 10 widgets, how does the math change?

It'd be something like 100 / 5 up to 10 (so 50 hours burned); then 50 / 6 for the remainder because I have run out of pre-made widgets.

Is there a simpler or more compact way to write out this formula?

Comment: This problem is pretty easy if you view getting 10 free widgets as the same as getting 10 free hours. So it's just 110/6.

Comment: @K.defaoite Oh, that's clever.  That will likely help, thanks.

Comment: @K.defaoite  Just thinking through the cases, what about when I have 50 free widgets?  The free hours idea doesn't quite work then, because I should be constrained by the original 100/5, so it should be 120/6 (keeping the constraint in mind) rather than 150/6.

Comment: This is a good point. I hadn't thought of this. I'll post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is easiest to just split into cases. Since you are a programmer, you shouldn't have any trouble implementing something like this. Suppose a widget takes time $t_{\text{w}}$ to make, a gadget takes one widget and another $t_{\text{g}}$ hours to make, and we have $H$ hours in total, starting initially with $W$ spare widgets. Let $G$ be the total number of gadgets we can make in the allotted time. If $W\geq H/t_{\text{g}}$ then simply
$$G=\lfloor H/t_{\text{g}}\rfloor$$
However, if this is not the case, then
$$G=\left\lfloor W+\frac{H-W\cdot t_{\text{g}}}{t_{\text{g}}+t_{\text{w}}}\right\rfloor$$
Example - if we have $H=100$ hours, a widget takes $t_{\text{w}}=1$ hour to make, and a gadget takes $t_{\text{g}}=5$ hours and one widget to make, and we start with say $13$ spare widgets, then
$$G=\left\lfloor13+\frac{100-13\times 5}{6}\right\rfloor=\lfloor 18.833...\rfloor=18 \text{ gadgets }$$

Comment: Yup, the more I thought about it, the more just having two separate cases makes sense.   Thanks again.

Comment: @jpreed00 No problem! Problems like these can be a bit fiddly, but the implementation is simple once you write the equation down.